# I am getting multiple errors in my android project?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Basic AndroidRadar app but when I  run code I am getting multiple errors below

error

> error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity.     null
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details     Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details

I have tried all answers from StackOverflow it is still giving an error
below my xml activity_main.xml file where I have implemented radar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <it.smasini.radar.RadarView
        app:load_async_image="true"
        app:center_pin_color="#00FFFFFF"
        app:background_color="#00FFFFFF"
        app:arrow_color="#4CAF50"
        app:pins_radius="100"
        android:id="@+id/radar_view"
        app:radar_background="@drawable/radar_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What the class is `it.smasini.radar.RadarView`?

Comment: it is dependcy @DimaRostopira

Comment: implementation  'it.smasini:android-radar:1.0'

Comment: Did you sync your project with gradle files successful?

Comment: Double-check the actual content of your XML file, e.g., if you cut-and-pasted from a website or something there may be garbage in there. You can try re-creating the file in your IDE as well, and take care to only type in characters.

Comment: @Dave Newton I will create new file and I will try to as you told me

Comment: @Dave Newton it is not working what do you think real problem is I have recreated and paste the code not working (((

Comment: Since I don't know explicitly what you did I don't know if you did it right. Check the file with a hex dump utility and see what's at the opening.

Comment: I have done as you told me no error in xml file

Comment: @Dave Newton what do you think main problem invalidate cache restart also not working

Comment: I told you what I thought the main problem was--I think you have garbage characters at the beginning of, or somewhere in, your XML file. Without seeing a hex dump of it, I cannot rule out that possibility, and it would lead to the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Dave Newton I have download file to online a hex dump utility what is the next step I never use a hex dump utility

Comment: Dump the file in hex and look at it? I can't actually see what you're doing--how would I know?

Comment: @Dave Newton I have looked no errors

Comment: I find that unlikely, but okay. In that case, no clue. It might be nice to include a link to the file, or the hex dump output, so that can be independently verified. Without the original source file there's no way anybody can really help. (The actual file, not cut-and-pasted contents.)

Comment: @Dave Newton please check this link below https://imageshack.com/a/img922/4785/A0kMpV.png

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, but it's difficult from an image. I'd still suspect the XML file's contents, though.

Comment: @Dave Newton what is your suggestion in this case

Comment: Delete the file, recreate manually in the IDE, by typing.

Comment: Thanks it is working for your effort @DaveNewton

Comment: You should add an answer with what fixed it.

Comment: I have deleted activity_main.xml file recreated recreate manually in the IDE then it fixed issue.